# Estamos migrando o Traducir para nossa infraestrutura interna

Tags: debate, tradução, localização, internacionalização

Já faz muito tempo desde que [começamos a usar o Traducir no Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272) em 2018. Originalmente, o construímos como código aberto, o que não apenas nos permite aceitar contribuições dos usuários, mas, mais importante, nos permite discutir os problemas que estavam enfrentando e ideias de implementação.

O mais impressionante do Traducir é que nós, as comunidades internacionais, conseguimos resolver um problema que enfrentamos usando uma ferramenta construída pelas próprias comunidades internacionais.

Em termos de esforço, basicamente gastamos muito tempo em 2018 para fazer o Traducir funcionar – mas desde então, o único trabalho de manutenção significativo que precisei fazer foi reescrever o frontend sem usar o React (acabou dando muito trabalho para manter). Fora isso, tem funcionado muito bem – mesmo quando começamos a usá-lo em outros sites internacionais (no momento, é o que todas as nossas comunidades internacionais usam para enviar traduções).

Veja este gráfico – fico orgulhoso de termos construído algo que simplesmente funciona e requer tanta manutenção:

[image: gráfico do GitHub mostrando contribuições dadas ao projeto Traducir]

Desde o início do Traducir, ele funciona na minha infraestrutura pessoal. Originalmente, isso não era uma grande preocupação, já que as traduções eram revisadas manualmente pelos gerentes da comunidade antes de serem lançadas nos sites - mas desde que esse processo se tornou automatizado, fiquei um pouco preocupado em hospedá-lo sozinho (já que meu foco é desenvolvimento de software e não um Engenheiro de Confiabilidade do site).

Quando saí do Stack Overflow pela primeira vez, transferi a propriedade do domínio traducir.win para o Stack Overflow, mas continuei executando-o em minha própria infraestrutura. Agora que estou deixando o Stack Overflow novamente (no final deste mês), adoraria tirar essa responsabilidade dos meus ombros também.

É por isso que estamos planejando mover o Traducir para a infraestrutura do Stack Overflow, onde a empresa irá protegê-lo e mantê-lo funcionando.

Como parte dessa mudança, estamos planejando:

1. Fork do [repositório atual do Traducir](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) para o repositório GitHub privado do Stack Overflow
2. Arquivar o repositório atual (para que o código ainda possa ser referenciado publicamente, mas que fique claro que o repositório público não é mais mantido)
3. Mover a aplicação para a infraestrutura do Stack Overflow

Isso significa que a comunidade não poderá enviar PR's para corrigir problemas por conta própria. No entanto, quando analisamos o histórico de contribuição do código, descobrimos que a última contribuição significativa de não funcionário foi em 2019 (e mesmo assim, foi de um ex-funcionário). Isso não terá nenhum impacto em como a comunidade usa o Traducir para enviar traduções (além de alguns minutos de inatividade), mas queríamos deixar todos cientes do que está acontecendo.

Então essa é a notícia! Estou aliviado por entregar o Traducir ao Stack Overflow. :) Se você tiver comentários ou perguntas, deixe-os aqui. E se você encontrar algum problema com o Traducir (ou quiser sugerir melhorias), você sempre pode publicá-los no Meta (e os moderadores do site podem [encaminhá-los para a atenção da equipe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/238921) se necessário).

PS Obrigado a [Charlotte](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/248038/charlotte) por traduzir este post!

Comment: Não sei qual o motivo que o leva a se desligar da SE, mas sucesso em sua empreitada.

Comment: Muito obrigado! este tem sido um trabalho muito divertido de 6 anos e meio

Comment: Quando leio "vai ficar sob responsabilidade da SE" fico com ainda menos vontade de usar a comunidade... Ainda por cima tornando tudo privado

Answer (score 7):

Eu ainda gostaria que o processo de tradução fosse mais automático.

Hoje continua sendo basicamente:

1. SE muda algo no site
2. Aparecem mensagens em inglês em alguns lugares
3. Comunidade traduz

E entre os passos 2 e 3, podem levar alguns dias (agravado por haver poucos usuários ativos, e estes estarem cansados de traduzir, só pra ver tudo acontecer de novo).

Eu queria muito que fosse pensada outra maneira que não dependesse tanto da comunidade. Mesmo que a gente consiga resolver rapidamente, não gosto que exista este intervalo entre perceber o problema e resolvê-lo, pois o problema nem deveria existir pra começo de conversa.

Considerando que a equipe - até onde sei - tem pelo menos uma pessoa fluente em cada um dos idiomas (russo, português e espanhol - não tenho certeza quanto a japonês), e que a necessidade de tradução não tem sido tão frequente (ou seja, não vai demandar tanto assim da equipe), acredito que seja perfeitamente possível ter uma versão previamente traduzida sempre que o passo 1 acima é feito.

Ou seja, em vez de quebrar e esperar a comunidade consertar, é melhor nem quebrar.

Se não for possível, então que haja pelo menos um meio-termo. Por exemplo, que a gente fique sabendo com antecedência que serão criadas novas strings, podendo inclusive já ir trabalhando na tradução antes da implantação, diminuindo ou até eliminando o tempo entre os passos 2 e 3 (mas ainda acho que quanto menos depender da comunidade, melhor - [já temos problemas demais](/q/8786/112052) pra lidar no dia-a-dia, com a diferença que [nem somos pagos pra isso](/posts/comments/38398)).

Comment: Note that the CM team itself only has folks fluent in Portuguese and Russian (of the languages used on our international sites), though we have a Japanese contractor as well. (The one CM fluent in Spanish no longer works here; there may be other staff here who know Spanish, but they're not CMs.) Overall, I agree that we need a better process for handling translations, rather than relying on a process where any changes to the text break existing translations and 0the community has to retranslate those strings afterwards (while English text is shown on the site in the interim).